# How to find median in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, median, partition

I have the following sql query which gives me the total h_time grouped by month, week and day. Instead I want the median h_time for month, week and day. How do I do that in Oracle SQL?

```
 SELECT DAY,

MEDIAN(H_TIME) AS HANDLE_TIME

FROM(
    select 
MONTH, WEEK, DAY,

    CASE 
        WHEN C.JOINED IS NOT NULL
            THEN (NVL(C.TOTAL_TALK,0) + NVL(C.TOTAL_HOLD,0) + (NVL((C.DATETIME - C.START_DATETIME)*86400,0)) )/86400 
            ELSE 0 END AS H_TIME

from TABLE1 C


LEFT JOIN TABLE2 S
ON S.ID = C.ID
where c.direct = 'Inbound'
)

where UPPER(ITEM1) like 'SOMETHING%' 

GROUP BY


DAY
```

OUTPUT:

```
DAY              HANDLE_TIME
14-APR-17   .00567129629629629629629629629629629629629
15-APR-17   0
17-APR-17   0
17-APR-17   .00422453703703703703703703703703703703703
19-APR-17   .00269675925925925925925925925925925925925
19-APR-17   0
19-APR-17   0
19-APR-17   .00824074074074074074074074074074074074074
```

Comment: On line 3 @GurwinderSingh Or you mean in the subquery?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Missed copying. Sorry, updated the query.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output for that data.

Comment: @trincot desired output should be median of H_TIME for each "DAY". But in the output I'm still getting multiple entries for the same date

Comment: I am not looking for a semantic of the desired output, but a ***worked out example*** to avoid misunderstandings about the scope of each median.

Comment: I don't understand you

Comment: Please provide example data (rows with actual values) for tables TABLE1 and TABLE2, and tell us what you expect the output to be for *that* data.

Comment: Are you sure that some of your "DAY" values do not contain a time component (making them different) that you are not displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably come from the time part that the DATE type carry (even if you don't explicitly set it).

To get rid of it you can use the trunc function.

Replace:

```
SELECT DAY,
```

By:

```
SELECT trunc(DAY)
```

And:

```
GROUP BY DAY
```

By:

```
GROUP BY trunc(DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing :

```
SUM(H_TIME) AS HANDLE_TIME
```

by :

```
MEDIAN(H_TIME) AS HANDLE_TIME
```

(line 3)

EDIT:
For the months, replace:

```
select 
MONTH, WEEK, DAY,
```

By:

```
select 
MONTH,
```

And:

```
GROUP BY

MONTH
,WEEK
,DAY
```

By:

```
GROUP BY 
MONTH
```

For the weeks, replace:

```
select 
MONTH, WEEK, DAY,
```

By:

```
select 
MONTH, WEEK,
```

And:

```
GROUP BY

MONTH
,WEEK
,DAY
```

By:

```
GROUP BY 
MONTH
,WEEK
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will just give me the median h_time for the "DAY", right? Then how do I get it for month and week? Because earlier when I was doing sum, that sums all the h_times for the "DAY" and then I create a pivot table in excel and I'm able to get sums for week and month as well. But for median this will not work I guess.

Comment: No, it won't. In order to do that you'll have to play with your group by.
(remove day for having weekly median and week for monthly one)

Comment: You mean create separate queries? Because I want for all, day, week and month

Comment: Yes, i think that would be the most effective way because you can't show analysis for days and week or week and months on the same query without data redundancy which is BAD :).

Comment: @Arman - the big issue is that, while the sum of partial sums equals the overall global sum, the same is NOT true for medians. (Neither is it true for averages, for that matter.) There is no way to compute median times for the week or month, by just knowing the medians at the "day" level, by pivoting or in any other manner.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that there are not the same amount of medians for months than there are for weeks. same goes for days. if you try to do it with one query, you'll face a problem with data consistency.

Comment: @AxelPaccalin Yeah, I understand. So for my above query, if I just replace sum(h_time) by median(h_time), it will give me median for the "DAY", right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.
I've edited my answer to give you info on how to do months and week too.

Comment: @AxelPaccalin I tried what you suggested. I've updated my question above to show the output I'm getting when I'm doing group by DAY. Why is it not being grouped by day, because it's showing me multiple entries for single date.

Comment: since this is kind of another question I'll make a new answer, so those who will come to this post won't be lost.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the `median()` function, it's the `group by` column.

Oracle DATE datatype is actually a DATETIME, e.g. 2017-05-24 08:09:11. So when comparing dates we have to take the time element into consideration.

The easiest way to do this is by truncating the date value, which sets the time to midnight. So in your case that would look like this:

```
SELECT trunc(day) as DAY,
       MEDIAN(H_TIME) AS H_TIME
FROM (
    ...
)
group by trunc(day)
```

This solution is better than using `to_char()` to remove the time element because the datatype remains DATE. So if you sort the results `order by trunc(day)` you get the expected calendar order, whereas sorting on `to_char(day)` would give an unexpected alphanumeric ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use to_char(DAY) in group by and select statement