# SQL Median function not working

Tags: sql, oracle, median

I'm trying to find the median using SQL. In the below query, I'm grouping by "DAY", so that means for all the h_time(s) for that day, it should find the median and only one value per day should come in the output.

```
SELECT DAY,

MEDIAN(H_TIME) AS H_TIME

FROM(
    select 
MONTH, WEEK, DAY,

    CASE 
        WHEN C.JOINED IS NOT NULL
            THEN (NVL(C.TOTAL_TALK,0) + NVL(C.TOTAL_HOLD,0) + (NVL((C.DATETIME - C.START_DATETIME)*86400,0)) )/86400 
            ELSE 0 END AS H_TIME

from TABLE1 C


LEFT JOIN TABLE2 S
ON S.ID = C.ID
where c.direct = 'Inbound'
)

where UPPER(ITEM1) like 'SOMETHING%' 

GROUP BY
DAY
```

However, I'm getting the below output:

```
DAY              H_TIME
14-APR-17   .00567129629629629629629629629629629629629
15-APR-17   0
17-APR-17   0
17-APR-17   .00422453703703703703703703703703703703703
19-APR-17   .00269675925925925925925925925925925925925
19-APR-17   0
19-APR-17   0
19-APR-17   .00824074074074074074074074074074074074074
```

Why am I getting multiple lines for the same day? This means that the median function is not working as expected.

Comment: You already posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44118860/how-to-find-median-in-sql)